# Add User input from redux-form to the state as an array

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to put data that I receive from redux-form into my state. When the user submits the form, then an object is created, but I am not able to push this data into the users array. Here is my code:

```
class UserControlPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { users: []};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit=(values) => {
    const newUser = this.state.users;

    newUser.push(addUser(values));

    this.setState({ users: newUser });
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div>
            <legend>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> User creation
            </legend>
            <UserCreation onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({addUser}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(users) {
  return { users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserControlPage);
```

My first try was the following code:

```
  handleSubmit=(values) => {
    this.setState({users: addUser(values)});
  }
```

I guess that the problem must be that I did not initate the users state properly or mapped it correctly. But I have no real clue.

**Update:**
An object does successfully get created, but unfortunately, that seems to be out of the store. So I get a users object with the data from the form, but in my store, there is nothing.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for here is redux-form's [FieldArray](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FieldArray.md/) or [props.array](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/) options, as they are meant to handle array data in forms. Also since you are using redux and redux-form it seems odd to be using React's component state to try and store this data.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I try to store the data in the component state, but my reducer seems not to update my store. I get the data from the form via the handlesubmit function, so that at least works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I did not properly map my state to the store. I change handleSubmit() from:

```
  handleSubmit=(values) => {
    addUser(values);
  }
```

to

```
  handleSubmit=(values) => {
    this.props.addUser(values);
  }
```

and my state mapping from

```
function mapStateToProps(users) {
  return { users };
}
```

to

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users };
}
```

I also deleted this line in the constructor:

```
this.state = { users: []};
```